# how to create multiple terminal tabs and name each of them using shell script

Tags: tabs, gnome-terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

tab="--tab"
cmd="bash -c 'set-title hey';bash"
foo=""

for i in 1 2 3; do
      foo+=($tab -e "$cmd")         
done

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

In bashrc file i pasted a function set-title, and after running this script creates 3 tabs but bash command does not executes ???